# Show created date of all binary logs

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a way to extend the SHOW BINARY LOGS command to show the created date, or to at least show the time range each log is applicable for.

Is there a way to do this within MySQL or am I going to have to read each log individually to check what time period it covers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't store metadata about binary logs (well, it does, but only to control current and/or executed commands, not about the binlog themselves).

You can use `SHOW BINLOG EVENTS` to read the actual binlogs, but that most likely will not be helpful, and will be very slow (it just read the logs). Yes, **the only way I can think of is to read the actual logs with `mysqlbinlog`** and check the second line after the log position of the first and last events.

```
# at 256
#181130  9:28:36 server id 123  end_log_pos 545
```

If you don't need exact dates, there may be a shortcut for avoid reading the whole log- **you can use the mtime (last modified time) of the filesystem metadata to get an aproximation of when it was last written** (but not that will not be 100% acurate- flushing may be delayed by the filesystem, and the time the log was written may be different than that of when one the transaction was executed. But it may be a shortcut if you just want to find a particular event before reading just the one you are intereted in.